# Use dictionary value from if in statement

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a need for an If/Else statement in my Django (3.1.5) template check if a value exists in a dictionary (very popular concept). My challenge here is now trying to use the value from the dictionary it matched on.

I know i can use a for loop and then use another if to match again when that value exists but i am wondering if there is a shorter way to do what i am looking for.

For example, in my template i have 2 query sets, `config` and `user_settings` that i pass to the template. What i do is check if the name from the `config` exists in the `user_setting` dictionary, then I use the `config` details in a form. What I want to do is take the "total" field from `user_settings` dictionary that matched on the if in statement. In the below code the, the piece i am talking about is on line 6 `value='{{user_setting.total}}'`. This clearly doesn't work but can i do something like that to reduce the amount of code?

```
{% for c in config %}
    {% if c.location == 'Dashboard' %}
        {% if c.name in user_settings.all %}
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="{{c.web_friendly_name}}">{{c.name}}</label>
            <input class="form-control" data-type="dashboard" type="text" id="{{c.web_friendly_name}}" name="{{c.name}}" value="{{user_setting.total}}">
            <input type="hidden" name="{{c.web_friendly_name}}_total" value="yes">
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="{{c.web_friendly_name}}">{{c.name}}</label>    
            <input class="form-control" data-type="dashboard" type="text" id="{{c.web_friendly_name}}" name="{{c.name}}" value="5">
            <input type="hidden" name="{{c.web_friendly_name}}_total" value="yes">
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    settings = Setting.objects.all()
    user_settings = UserSetting.objects.filter(user=request.user, enabled=True).values_list('setting__name', flat=True)
    return render(request, 'settings/index.html', {
        'config': settings,
        'user_settings': user_settings,
    })
```

Comment: I would do this *complex* logic in the view itself. btw, can you add your views?

Comment: Please do *not* write business logic in the templates. Templates should only be concerned about *rendering* things.

Comment: There's no way to access a dict by its key in the template (apart from iterating over its items). You could write a custom templatetag that does this, but that approach would add even more complexity overall. You'd be better off handling the logic in your view or possibly adding a custom `@cached_property` to one of your models. But it's hard to be specific without seeing your views.py or models.py.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added my views but its dirt simple. I am doing the logic in the template as I didn't think this was overly complex. However, with another for loop in the mix it will start to get there. I understand it is not efficient nor a best practice. I will move this logic to the view as JPG and Willem suggested.